# Неопределенная php константа во время AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

реализую `mvs-pattern` для своего сайта на `php`, во время отправки AJAX-запроса возникла проблема, в AJAX-ответ приходит ошибка: `Use of undefined constant ROOT...`.
**Эта константа определена в корневом файле проекта** (перед вызовом роутера) и служит абсолютным путем для подключения контроллеров, моделей и тд. `Controlller`и `Action` выглядят примерно так:

*UserContrller.php*

```
<?php
require ROOT.'/models/UserModel.php';

class UserController{
  ...
  actionSubmit(){
  //действия
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: если пишет что не определена то значит не определена, перепиши константу заного, в обоих местах, иногда бывает что написал например часть на русском часть на английском. Выглядит одинокого а в итоге не определена. Если не в этом дело.То тогда кроме тебя встряли тебе кто то поможет ,разобраться пот тем кусочкам кода что ты прислал. Ну и в конце концов, тестирование не кто не отменял , напиши подобное в другом виде , покрути туда сюда, сделай без require, Посмотри echo или в отладчике что лежит в ROOT переменой.

Comment: Дело в том что при ajax-запросе не происходит подгрузка `index.php` где инициализируется константа. Вопрос стоит как можно передать или сохранить эту константу.

Comment: Ну передельный так чтоб происходила php не javascript с кучей асинхронности, выполнение идет шаг за шагом.

Comment: Помогло, принудительное отключение асинхроности в ajax

Comment: Говорил же покрути туда сюда, разобраться в подобном ,не видя всего когда и что происходит, удаленно встряли кто то б понял в чем и где суть.